# docker wants to access drive c do you want to share it?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I've been learning about Docker containers and asp.net core on Azure through a pluralsight tutorial.
I created a hello world asp net core 2.1 app, and added docker support through VS, for it to run on Linux.

While it runs fine on Azure, when running locally (Docker is on linux mode locally) with debug in VS, Docker prompts me with this question: 
docker wants to access drive c do you want to share it?

I don't know why this happens and if it is too dangerous to "share" my C drive.
Why should I share anything? Who am I sharing it with? Can't I just "Share" a folder?

Answer (score 5):

You're "sharing" the c drive with your internal docker VM (Docker runs on a MobyLinux VM through Hyper-V on Windows)

This should be safe to do.